# Charging circuit for Lithium Iron Phosphate batteries

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, lithium

This question is regarding charging circuit for Lithium Iron Phosphate batteries.

I have a pack of Lithium Iron Phosphate batteries rated 3.2 V / 7.5Ah which will drive a circuit. According to the data sheet provided by the vendors, they have told me to just keep voltage under 3.6 V and maximum current of 1000 milli Amperes while charging and I should be fine.

My charging source is a solar panel of rated 5.5 V and 500 mA. Since they have a protection circuit which will take care of Constant Current & Constant Voltage , short-circuit and over charge/ undercharge, can I just use a 3.6V Zener Diode and a forward biased pn junction Diode in the circuit to ensure the voltage does not shoot above 3.6V and if the panel's voltage is below 3.6V, the diode is going to protect it.

Is this approach okay? Or is it complex than this? Thanks.

Comment: can you add empty lines ("paragraphs") at logical sections in your text? This is unnecessarily hard to read. Also, I'd recommend you pick *either* writing out Units ("Volts") or abbreviations ("V"). I prefer the latter, but please don't mix these two variants.

Comment: Thank you! Much better to read, and a question good enough to warrant an upvote!

Comment: @MarcusMüller New to posting questions. Thank you too for the guide. :) Any info on the subject matter would be appreciated since you have a background on batteries.

Comment: Didn't you mean 3.6 V Zener diode?

Comment: @AliChen Sorry, I meant it so. Edited it now.

Comment: Zener diodes are not precision instruments : the zener voltage can vary quite a lot from 3.6V according to the current through it. Its datasheet should have more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that TP 5000 http://vrtp.ru/index.php?act=Attach&type=post&id=585578 fits my requirement.